# Python: setting apart speech from empty audio records

Tags: python, anaconda, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to write a Python-3.6 script that would set apart empty .aif audio records (i.e. containing ambient noise only) from those which contain speech. My aim is **not** to recognize speech content - firstly, it's not English, and secondly, it's not needed for my purposes.

Nonetheless, I failed to invent something better than to use SpeechRecognition with pocketsphinx for resolving this issue. My idea was quite primitive:

```
        import speech_recognition as sr

        r = sr.Recognizer()
        emptyRecords = []
        for fname in os.listdir(TESTDIR):
            with sr.AudioFile(TESTDIR + fname) as source:
                recorded = r.record(source)
                recognized = r.recognize_sphinx(recorded)
            if len(recognized) <= 10:
                print("{} seems to be an empty record.".format(fname))
                emptyRecords.append(fname)
```

That is, I tried to transform recorded audios into lists of strings and to separate those lists according to an 'intuitive' threshold of 10 words, since sometimes pocketsphinx recognized background noise as a sparse sequence of several interjections. However, this took an extremely long time because of unnecessary speech recognition process - for each record I only needed to check whether it containted more than 10 words and nothing more. As far as I understand from SpeechRecognition's docs, the Recognizer class doesn't contain any attributes or methods that would limit the number of words to be recognized.

Could someone suggest a better idea for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try webrtcvad lib. Set aggressiveness mode and test with your recorded data.

https://pypi.org/project/webrtcvad/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, this lib solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a STFT (Short TIME Fourier Transform)

Getting the total energy in the signal and comparing it to the energy that is located in the human vocal range (300 Hz to 3000 Hz). (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)

Here is a simple stft using numpy and a fft size of 1024, you can use it https://github.com/JPabloVasquez/SimpleAudioTools

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try your solution too, although webrtcvad has already solved my issue.